# Consequences in number theory if we have ${\sigma}^{k}(x)\equiv 0\pmod{x}$ for all positive integers $k>1$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I asked [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/211567/51189) $4$ years ago in MO , but There is no affirmative answer  about existence of such integer  $k>1$ for which ${\sigma}^{k}(x)\equiv 0\pmod{x}$ hold , My question here : What are the consequence of this claim if it would be hold ?

**Note:**$${\sigma}^{k}(x )=\sigma(\sigma(\sigma(\sigma(\cdots x))))$$